# How can I best convert a bbcode export from phpbb to ordinary HTML using JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, html, bbcode

I'm trying to take an export from a phpbb forum and import it into one that uses standard HTML.

I looked around and do see there are bbcode to HTML converters here and there, for example `https://coursesweb.net/javascript/convert-bbcode-html-javascript_cs`

One problem is the code I'm trying to convert also includes extra characters with each markdown tag. For example, one post looks like this:

```
[quote=&quot;debable&quot;:1qp926wi]Do anybody have any ideas for healthy&quot;treats&quot; for little kids lunch boxes.[/quote:1qp926wi]

[color=#BF0000:1qp926wi]Look over the goodies Jennifer packs for her son in her blog Vegan Lunch Box:[/color:1qp926wi]

[url:1qp926wi]http&#58;//veganlunchbox&#46;blogspot&#46;com/[/url:1qp926wi]
```

In this example all the [...] tags have an extra :1qp926wi added. And those characters, whatever they are, are different from post to post.

Is there a good way to convert bbcode like this, using JavaScript regular expressions, to HTML and ignoring those extra characters?

Thanks.